# K means clustering where centroid is a node

Tags: clustering, centroids

How would you approach a k mean clustering where the calculated centroids have to be on the same position as one of the nodes?
[image: example]

as you can see we have 2 centroids which are arguably the center of each cluster while being "ontop" of a node.

Is there already a name for this problem? I couldn't find anything related to it.

Comment: Are you asking how to do it using a particular GIS software?

Comment: Im asking how to do it algorithmically using python for example. since im fairly new to this stack, id be interested in using a particular gis software as well